# Prove that if $x$ is irrational, then $\frac{x+1}{x-1}$ is irrational

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, fractions, irrational-numbers

I have to prove that if $x$ is **irrational**, then $$\frac{x+1}{x-1}$$ is **irrational** too,
 but I'm not sure where to start from.

Could someone give me a clue?

Comment: If $y=(x+1)/(x-1)$, then what is $x$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $$\frac{x+1}{x-1}=r\in\mathbb Q$$
Thus, $r\neq1$, $$x=\frac{r+1}{r-1},$$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

If $y$ is irrational then $y+q,q\cdot y,\frac{q}{y}$  are irrational, if $q\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}.$

We have
$$\frac{x+1}{x-1}=\frac{(x-1)+2}{x-1}=1+\frac{2}{x-1}.$$
From  $x$ irrational follows $x-1$ irrational, therefore is  $\frac{2}{x-1}$ irrational and so $\frac{2}{x-1}+1$ is irrational.